# Python - replace multiple lines in Python Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I'm new with Python!

I have a form where I'm reading and writing everything ok, the replace is working fine in the first input, but it's not working in my second input.

For example I have my word 1 = Toy, if I change it for "house" it overwrites my .txt very well, but if I do with my word 2 = house, nothing happens.

This is my code Flask:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,flash,request,redirect
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
from lines import word_one,word_two

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def change_line():
    error= 'Cambios exitosos.'
    replace = word_one()
    replacetwo = word_two()
    try:
        if request.method =="POST":
            word = request.form ['word']
            words = request.form ['words']
            filedata= None
            rem = None
            with open('line.txt','r') as f:
                filedata = f.read()
                rem = f.read()

                filedata = filedata.replace(replace , word + "\n" )
                rem = rem.replace(replacetwo , words + "\n" )

            with open('line.txt','w') as f:
                f.write(filedata)
                f.write(rem)

    except BaseException as e:
        print e 
    return render_template('line.html')

@app.route('/')
def showLine():
    wordone = word_one()
    wordtwo = word_two()
    return render_template('line.html', wordone=wordone, wordtwo=wordtwo)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this is my .txt

```
wordone Toy
wordtwo house
```

this is my .html

```
<form method="post" name="test">
                            <h4>Chaging Values with POST Method</h4>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">word 1 : </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="word" value="{{ wordone }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">word 2 : </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="words" value="{{ wordtwo }}">
                            </div>


                            <input type="submit" value="Save Changes!">


    </form>
```

As word 1 is working, my only problem is with word 2..

Here's my output in client:

[Here is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c10zx.png)

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong here. How should the output look?

Comment: If I change the word 2 input nothing happens, but if I do the same in word 1 input it overwrites the form and my .txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this in your code:

```
        with open('line.txt','r') as f:
            filedata = f.read()
            filedata = filedata.replace(replace , word + "\n" )
            filedata = filedata.replace(replacetwo , words + "\n" )

        with open('line.txt','w') as f:
            f.write(filedata)
```

No need to read and write the same content twice.